# XML QDomElement comparison made general - C++/Qt

Tags: c++, xml, qt, parsing, binary

I implemented a routine C++/Qt to compare QDomElement in most general case.

```
bool XMLtools::compare( QDomElement & element1, QDomElement & element2 )
{
    QString tag1 = element1.tagName() ;   
    QString tag2 = element2.tagName() ;
    if ( tag1 != tag2 )
        return false ;
    QList<QDomElement> elts1 = getChildElements(element1);
    QList<QDomElement> elts2 = getChildElements(element2);
    QDomElement c1, c2, tmp ;

    QString name1, name_tmp, text1, text2 ;
    if(elts1.size() != elts2.size())
        return false ;
    if(elts1.size() == 0)
    {
        text1 = c1.text() ;
        text2 = c2.text() ;

        if( text1 != text2 )
            return false ;
    }
    for ( int i = elts1.size() - 1 ; i > -1 ; i-- ) 
    {
        c1 = elts1.at(i);
        QString name1 = c1.tagName();

        for( int j = elts2.size() - 1 ; j > -1 ; j-- )
        {
            tmp = elts2.at(j) ;
            name_tmp = tmp.tagName() ;

            if( name_tmp == name1 )
            {
                c2 = tmp ;
                break ;
            }

            if( j == 0 )
                return false ; 
        }
        if ( ! compare(c1, c2) )
            return false ;      
    }
    return true ;
}
```

1. Can all QDomNode elements be compared using this method (ie. comparing text()) ?

1. In particular, should i be cautious with special cases, as `QDomCDATASection` elements and binary format ?
2. if a `QDomNode` contains binary data, how to comare them, returning true when same data is inside ?

Thanks !

Comment: Even comparation of rather comles xml with itself fails with your code. Consider having 2 elements with the same tag and different content: `xml: <a>x</a><a>y</a>; xml2: <a>y</a><a>x</a>`

Comment: @Lol4t0 answered with working one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with Qt method `NodeValue()` that converts to `QString` the value of a `QDomNode` regardless of its type. My compare function is the following:

```
bool XMLtools::compare( QDomElement & element1, QDomElement & element2 )
{
    QString tag1 = element1.tagName() ;  //attribute("Name") ;
    QString tag2 = element2.tagName() ;

    if ( tag1 != tag2 )
        return false ;

    QList<QDomElement> elts1 = getChildElements(element1);
    QList<QDomElement> elts2 = getChildElements(element2);
    QDomElement c1, c2 ;

    bool these_nodes_are_equal = true ;
    bool one_comparing_tag = false ;

    QString name1, name2, value1, value2 ;

    if(elts1.size() != elts2.size())
        return false ;

    if(elts1.size() == 0)
    {
        value1 = c1.nodeValue() ;
        value2 = c2.nodeValue() ;

        if( value1 != value2 )
            return false ;
    }

    for ( int i = elts1.size() - 1 ; i > -1 ; i-- ) 
    {
        c1 = elts1.at(i);
        QString name1 = c1.tagName();

        for( int j = elts2.size() - 1 ; j > -1 ; j-- )
        {
            c2 = elts2.at(j) ;
            name2 = c2.tagName() ;

            if( name2 == name1 )
            {
                one_comparing_tag = true ;
                if ( ! compare(c1, c2) ) // c1 and c2 are potential identical nodes
                    these_nodes_are_equal = false ;
                else
                {
                    these_nodes_are_equal = true ;
                    break ;
                }
            }
        }

        if( !one_comparing_tag ) // if no node in elts2 is corresponding to node in elts1
            return false ; 

        if ( !these_nodes_are_equal ) // if no node in elts2 could compare to this node in elts1
            return false;   
    }

    return true ;
}
```

Comment: Still do not work: `xml1: <r><a></a><a></a><b></b></r>, xml2: <r><a></a><b></b><b></b></r>`. Apparently different, but result is `true`.

Comment: You declare c1 and c2 w/o initializing and then use it. I guess rather than `value1 = c1.nodeValue() ; value2 = c2.nodeValue() ;` you mean `value1 = element1.nodeValue(); value2 = element2.nodeValue();`

Answer (score 1):

I came up to the following equality checking algorithm:

### Two nodes `a` and `b` are equal, if `a >= b` and `b>=a`

```
bool compare( QDomElement  element1, QDomElement  element2 )
{
    return ! lessThen(element1, element2) && !lessThen(element2, element1);
}
```

Now we only have to introduce

### Comparison algorithm

Now will use native `QString` compare function

First of all, in a general approach, we should compare not only `QDomElement`s, but every `QDomNode` in the Dom.

- If `a.nodeType < b.nodeType`, then `a < b`
- Otherwise, if `a.nodeName < b.nodeName`, then `a < b`
- Otherwise, if `a.children.size() < b.children().size()`, then `a < b`
- Otherwise, if `a.children().size() ==0 && b.children().size() ==0`, compare `nodeValue()`.
  Note, that this approach will work for both attribute and text nodes. QDomElement itself has no `nodeValue`. If it is some text, written inside element, element will have child node of text type. That is why `element.nodeValue()` call always return null string.
- Otherwise, sort all children of the given nodes, using `lessThen` compare function.
- Then, check for every children `c` belongs to `a` and `d` belongs to `b`:

  - If `d > c`, then `a > b`
  - If `c < d`, then `a < b`
  - Otherwise (`c==d`) continue comparing for the next `c` and `d`.
- if all `c` is equal to `d`, then `a == b`, and apparently `a < b` is wrong.

### Code, implementing this algorithm:

```
QList<QDomNode> getChildElements(const QDomNode& e)
{
    QList<QDomNode> r;
    for (int k = 0; k < e.childNodes().size(); ++k) {
        QDomNode n = e.childNodes().at(k);
        r << n;
    }
    return r;
}


bool lessThen( QDomNode  element1, QDomNode  element2 )
{
    if (element1.nodeType() != element2.nodeType()) {
        return element1.nodeType() < element1.nodeType();
    }
    QString tag1 = element1.nodeName() ;
    QString tag2 = element2.nodeName() ;

    //qDebug() << tag1 <<tag2;
    if ( tag1 != tag2 )
        return tag1 < tag2;

    QList<QDomNode> elts1 = getChildElements(element1);
    QList<QDomNode> elts2 = getChildElements(element2);


    QString value1, value2 ;

    if(elts1.size() != elts2.size())
        return elts2.size() < elts1.size() ;

    if(elts1.size() == 0)
    {
        value1 = element1.nodeValue();
        value2 = element2.nodeValue();

        //qDebug() <<value1 << value2 << (value1 < value2);
        return value1 < value2;

    }

    qSort(elts1.begin(), elts1.end(), lessThen);
    qSort(elts2.begin(), elts2.end(), lessThen);
    //qDebug() << "comparing sorted lists";
    for(int  k = 0; k < elts1.size(); ++k) {
        if (!lessThen(elts1[k], elts2[k])) {
            if (lessThen(elts2[k], elts1[k])) {
                //qDebug() << "false!";
                return false;
            }
        }else {
            //qDebug() << "true!";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool compare( QDomElement  element1, QDomElement  element2 )
{
    return ! lessThen(element1, element2) && !lessThen(element2, element1);
}
```

Note, that comparison algorithm has extremely high complexity. It took about 10 minutes for me to process 2MB xml file (with *xml-should-be-equal-to-itself* test)

## Possible tests

Format:

```
description (desired result)
<xml1>
<xml2>
result
```

Tests:

```
different order (true) 
"<r>
 <a>x</a>
 <a>y</a>
</r>
" 
"<r>
 <a>y</a>
 <a>x</a>
</r>
" 
true 
different text (false) 
"<a>x</a>
" 
"<a>y</a>
" 
false 
different text with structure (false) 
"<a>x<b/>ddcd</a>
" 
"<a>y<b/>dede</a>
" 
false 
same structure different names (false) 
"<r>
 <a/>
 <a/>
 <b/>
</r>
" 
"<r>
 <a/>
 <b/>
 <b/>
</r>
" 
false 
same text with structure (true) 
"<a>y<b/>x</a>
" 
"<a>x<b/>y</a>
" 
true 
attributes vs text (false) 
"<a b="c"/>
" 
"<a>
 <b>c</b>
</a>
" 
false
```

Comment: could you further explain why you need lessThen helper, or point to corresponding doc ?? why to you need to distinguish between less and more each time you compare values ?? why aren't you simply looking if the nodes are different (by size, nb of children, ...)  ?? thanks

Comment: @madptr, I had to use `lessThen` to make nodes sortable: `qSort(elts1.begin(), elts1.end, lessThen)`. Here `lessThen` is my `lessThen`. Sorting is the easiest way of comparing missives. if we have 2 arrays `a` and `b` and they a sorted, we only need to check, if `a[k] == b[k]` to compare them, but if they are not sorted, we should implement some tricky algorithm, because neither comparing `a[k]` with b[k], nor comparing `a[i]` with `b[j]` for every pair `(i, j)` won't produce correct result.

Comment: really makes sense, your solution is great. which way do you think it can be time optimized ? i have an idea Qt QDomElement is a bottleneck and is slow in itself.

Comment: @madptr, I looked through your other questions about comparing xml: if you now _structure_ of data, storied in a file, you should parse xmls (with `QXmlStreamReader`) to some convenient form based on this knowledge, and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this doesn't take attributes into account.
Following is based on octoback's code but might be better (faster) when applied to Lol4t0's sorted version. I did not thoroughly test this.

```
bool compareElements (QDomElement & element1, QDomElement & element2)
{
    QString tag1 = element1.tagName ();  //attribute("Name") ;
    QString tag2 = element2.tagName ();

    if (tag1 != tag2)
        return false;

    QList<QDomElement> elts1 = getChildElements (element1);
    QList<QDomElement> elts2 = getChildElements (element2);

    bool these_nodes_are_equal = true;
    bool one_comparing_tag = false;

    QString name1, name2, value1, value2;

    if (elts1.size () != elts2.size ())
        return false;

    if (elts1.size () == 0)
    {
        value1 = element1.nodeValue ();
        if (!value1.isEmpty ())
        {
            value2 = element2.nodeValue ();
            if (!value2.isEmpty ())
            {
                if (value1 != value2)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        // attributes
        QDomNamedNodeMap attributes1 = element1.attributes ();
        QDomNamedNodeMap attributes2 = element2.attributes ();
        if (attributes1.size () != attributes2.size ())
            return false;
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < attributes1.size (); i1++)
        {
            QDomNode item1 = attributes1.item (i1);
            QString a1 = item1.nodeName ();
            if (!a1.isEmpty ())
            {
                bool found = false;
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < attributes2.size (); i2++)
                {
                    QDomNode item2 = attributes2.item (i2);
                    QString a2 = item2.nodeName ();
                    if (a1 == a2)
                    {
                        if (item1.nodeValue () != item2.nodeValue ())
                            return false;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found)
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }

    QDomElement c1, c2;
    for (int i = elts1.size () - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        c1 = elts1.at (i);
        name1 = c1.tagName ();

        for (int j = elts2.size () - 1; j > -1; j--)
        {
            c2 = elts2.at (j);
            name2 = c2.tagName ();

            if (name2 == name1)
            {
                one_comparing_tag = true;
                if (!compareElements (c1, c2)) // c1 and c2 are potential identical nodes
                    these_nodes_are_equal = false;
                else
                {
                    these_nodes_are_equal = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!one_comparing_tag) // if no node in elts2 is corresponding to node in elts1
            return false;

        if (!these_nodes_are_equal) // if no node in elts2 could compare to this node in elts1
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```